# Shopify Div won't get transparent. The Body Background should be seeable

Tags: css, shopify, shopify-template

I've got a problem on my Website: https://ola-ware.com/

i changed the background of the body to the white checked pattern you can see below at the website.
Actually i want this pattern to be seeable under all the element. Also the products which are PNG's.

I already tryed to set the background color of the Div's totransparent and header background color.
If i change the background image of the Div's to a transparent picture, it still just shows the white background instead of the checked pattern.

Maybe someone has some ideas how this could be fixed.
(I bought the This Shopify Theme - so i dont know the code very well. But can't find a line of code where the background-color isdefined to white.)

Thank you very much in advance!
Domo